# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Laravel 9 deployed in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed Laravel 9 application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However, when I access the login page, I get the following error.

[image: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

I have taken the following steps to solve the problem without any success.

I did run the `npm run build` to build the assets.

Then I installed `composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors` and included `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` in the `Kernal.php` file.

[image]

And here is the cors.php in the config folder.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

Load balancer configurations

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to setup https. http connections are blocked by default by modern browsers.

Comment: @Marcin I have configured it using Loadbalancer. And added an SSL certificate using Amazon Certification Manager. The only issue is in the login and register pages.

Comment: This may help, not PHP app but somewhat similar issue, https://medium.com/nordible/aws-elastic-load-balance-and-cors-issues-cbe084635cf0